# Почему значение полей экземпляров разное при использовании struct и class?

Tags: c#, struct

Помогите, плиз, понять, каким образом, при использовании структуры и класса, получается результат на консоле:

> поле класса change
>
> поле структуры xxx

Я понимаю, что есть разница в хранении данных на стеке и на хипе, но, что-то я впадаю в ступор смотря на этот пример.

Вот сам код:

```
class MyClass
    {
        public string change;
    }

public struct MyStruct
{
    public string change;
}

class Program
{
    static void ClassTaker(MyClass myClass)
    {
        myClass.change = "change";
    }

    static void StructTaker(MyStruct myStruct)
    {
        myStruct.change = "change";
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        MyClass class1 = new MyClass();
        MyStruct struct1 = new MyStruct();

        class1.change = "xxx";
        struct1.change = "xxx";

        ClassTaker(class1);
        StructTaker(struct1);

        Console.WriteLine("поле класса {0}", class1.change);
        Console.WriteLine("поле структуры {0}", struct1.change);
    }
}
```

Comment: это базовое отличие значимых типов от ссылочных. Передавая структуру в какую то функцию, вы передаете не ту же самую структуру, а её копию, и вот это `myStruct.change = "change";` изменяет копию изначальной структуры.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Различия в структурах и классах не только в том где они хранятся, но ещё в том, как они передаются в метод ([stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29606475/c-sharp-pass-by-value-vs-pass-by-reference)).

Классы - по ссылке. Это значит, что в метод передается только ссылка на этот объект, а не полностью объект, т.е. в памяти хранится один и тот же объект и все методы ссылаются на него.

Структуры - по значению. Это значит, что в метод передается **копия** вашего объекта, т.е. в методе будет хранится независимая копия, которая не будет никак влиять на оригинал.

Это и приводит к разному поведению. В вашем примере, когда вызывается `ClassTaker`, он получает ссылку на оригинальный объект, его меняет, а т.к. это один и тот же объект в памяти, то и в консоль выводится измененная строка. В `StruckTaker`, вы получаете копию, ее обновляете и просто "выбрасываете"/не используете нигде, и по этому оригинальный объект не изменяется и в консоль выводится старое значение.

И лучше почитать книги/статьи по .NET, там различия между классами и структурами более подробно описываются.

Comment: Благодарю Вас за помощь! Без рисование схемы не обошлось) Я читал и смотрел о таких разницах, но без практики сложно все это запоминать, вот на практике пытаюсь разобраться, получается!

Comment: Моя ошибка заключалась в том, что я мнимо считал что вызываю StruckTaker, а по факту, как Вы и сказали - он не используется. Все элементарно оказалось)

Comment: @RuslanKordik Вызов `StructTaker` происходит и он выполняется, но результат его работы ни на что не влияет, т.к. внутри себя изменил копию, а это копия "никому не нужна".